# How to do transpose in Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

[Transpose Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dccI4.png)

How can this be done in Polars? I'm trying to display some sales information, which I query and process in Polars, but not sure how to do this final transformation.

[Polars Docs](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.transpose.html) it seems that it's supported, but it's confusing how to actually write the code for this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just to note: It's considered common courtesy to at least include the code used to create the example dataframe when asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

I think `Year` needs to be an [index column](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/migration/pandas/#polars-does-not-have-a-multi-indexindex) in order for it to be done with just `.transpose()` (e.g. if you were using pandas)

As Polars [does not have indexes](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/migration/pandas/#polars-does-not-have-a-multi-indexindex), it would probably be more natural to use [`.melt()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.melt.html#polars.DataFrame.melt) + [`.pivot()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.pivot.html#polars.DataFrame.pivot)

```py
(df.melt("Year", variable_name="Product")
   .pivot("value", "Product", "Year")
)
```

```py
shape: (3, 4)
┌──────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ Product  ┆ 2018 ┆ 2019 ┆ 2020 │
│ ---      ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str      ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ Product1 ┆ 100  ┆ 120  ┆ 140  │
│ Product2 ┆ 130  ┆ 150  ┆ 170  │
│ Product3 ┆ 1    ┆ 2    ┆ 3    │
└──────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Comment: This is probably better than transpose since OP's example is extra easy. If, instead of years, it was a string, then after the transpose all the columns would be strings because of the first row and they'd need to be cast back to numbers.

Answer (score 1):

`transpose` is a little bit tricky because you have to manually rename the columns to be the first row.

#### Init df

```
df=pl.DataFrame(dict(
    Year=[2018,2019,2020],
    Product1=[100,120,140],
    Product2=[130,150,170],
    Product3=[1,2,3]
))
```

#### First try (not the solution)

```
df.transpose(include_header=True)
shape: (4, 4)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ column   ┆ column_0 ┆ column_1 ┆ column_2 │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str      ┆ i64      ┆ i64      ┆ i64      │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ Year     ┆ 2018     ┆ 2019     ┆ 2020     │
│ Product1 ┆ 100      ┆ 120      ┆ 140      │
│ Product2 ┆ 130      ┆ 150      ┆ 170      │
│ Product3 ┆ 1        ┆ 2        ┆ 3        │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

but you want the first row to be the column headers and not be part of the df itself. Here are two methods to do that.

#### Intermediate df method (easier to see what's happening)

```
df_t = df.transpose(include_header=True)
df_t.columns = [str(x) for x in df_t.slice(0,1).rows()[0]]
# doing slice(0,1) isn't strictly necessary but if you have a big df it'll 
# keep it from transforming the whole df to a list of tuples when you
# only need the first

df_t = df_t.rename({df_t.columns[0]:""})
# this rename is also not necessary but renames the first column to a blank string
# to match the example

df_t = df_t.slice(1) # this slice is necessary to get rid of the column headings
df_t


shape: (3, 4)
┌──────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│          ┆ 2018 ┆ 2019 ┆ 2020 │
│ ---      ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str      ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ Product1 ┆ 100  ┆ 120  ┆ 140  │
│ Product2 ┆ 130  ┆ 150  ┆ 170  │
│ Product3 ┆ 1    ┆ 2    ┆ 3    │
└──────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

#### "Single" line method (a bit hackier looking)

```
(
    df
    .transpose(include_header=True)
    .pipe(lambda df_t: (
    # using pipe here let's us work from the output of the transpose without setting global
    # intermediate variables. We just make a lambda and then chain everything from that 
    # df_t but it's only scoped in the lambda so it doesn't clutter up global vars.
        df_t
        .rename(
            { old_col:
                str(new_col) if new_col != df_t.slice(0,1).select(pl.first()).item() else "" 
                for old_col,new_col in zip(df_t.columns, df_t.slice(0,1).rows()[0])}
        )
        # In this method, we want to chain everything so we rename the columns with this
        # dictionary comprehension instead of setting df_t.columns
        # like before but it does the same thing
        .slice(1)
    ))
)

shape: (3, 4)
┌──────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│          ┆ 2018 ┆ 2019 ┆ 2020 │
│ ---      ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str      ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ Product1 ┆ 100  ┆ 120  ┆ 140  │
│ Product2 ┆ 130  ┆ 150  ┆ 170  │
│ Product3 ┆ 1    ┆ 2    ┆ 3    │
└──────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```